# Blazor WebAssembly. Add Authorize attribute at layout level

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I started from a visual studio template, a new Blazor WebAssembly with authentication and web API as the server-side.

My problem there is to protect all the pages and not just some pages. I tried to add :

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [Authorize]
```

to the MainLayout instead of all pages but without any luck.
I wanted to do that because I'm writing an admin and I don't want people to see the layout at all if there are not connected

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I wanted to do that because I'm writing an admin and I don't want
> people to see the layout at all if there are not connected

It can be understood that when the user is not logged in, they cannot enter any page, so we can `jump to the login page` at this time,right?

If so, you can achieve it by the following steps:

- First create a **RedirectToLogin.razor** page in the current blazor
  project.

  In the `OnInitializedAsync` method of this page, by judging whether
  there is currently a user logged in, and if not, redirect to the
  `Login` page.

  RedirectToLogin.razor:

  ```
  @inject NavigationManager Navigation
  @code {
      [CascadingParameter]
      private Task<AuthenticationState> AuthenticationStateTask { get; set; }

      protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
      {
          var authenticationState = await AuthenticationStateTask;

          if (authenticationState?.User?.Identity is null || !authenticationState.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
          {
              Navigation.NavigateTo("Identity/Account/Login", true);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- Then add the following code in **App.razor** to ensure that
  `NotAuthorized` will enter the `RedirectToLogin.razor` page:

  ```
  <CascadingAuthenticationState>
      <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
          <Found Context="routeData">
              <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                  <NotAuthorized>
                      <RedirectToLogin />
                  </NotAuthorized>
              </AuthorizeRouteView>
          </Found>
          <NotFound>
              <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                  <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
              </LayoutView>
          </NotFound>
      </Router>
  </CascadingAuthenticationState>
  ```
- Finally, in the **MainLayout.razor** page, a distinction is made
  between Authorized and NotAuthorized：

  ```
  @inherits LayoutComponentBase
  <AuthorizeView>
      <Authorized>
          <div class="sidebar">
              <NavMenu />
          </div>

          <div class="main">
              <div class="top-row px-4 auth">
                  <LoginDisplay />
                  <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
              </div>

              <div class="content px-4">
                  @Body
              </div>
          </div>
      </Authorized>
      <NotAuthorized>
          <RedirectToLogin />
      </NotAuthorized>
  </AuthorizeView>
  ```

Here is the test result:

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. I was not able to achieve it correctly, and I ended by wrapping <AuthorizeRouteView> inside a <AuthorizeView>. It was quite working correctly, but I felt it was not the correct way. Moreover, it appends multiple time the returnUrl value

Comment: I see that you used directly Identity/Account/Login. Why not create an intermediate view with <RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" /> like it's done in the default template? I notice it's the reason why it was failing on my side. If I use this intermediate page I get a blank page

Comment: @Dragouf, In fact, when user are not logged in, you can define any page you want to jump to. The path I provided is the login page under identity.

Comment: sure but since MainLayout is the default layout all pages will no be secured. I guess it's the reason why I get a blank page when I use a new page with <RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" /> component inside as it is in the example template of Visual Studio?

Comment: For future devs taking this approach, create a dummy layout for the `Authentication` page and leave the default `RedirectToLogin` component, so you can use the IdentityServer config instead of hardcoding a login URL.

Answer (score 5):

Putting @attribute [Authorize] in _Imports.razor seem to work. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60687879/require-authorization-on-all-blazor-pages). The accepted answer may not work correctly, in case route is not found. You can use different public layout (not MainLayout) though.

Comment: I have different issues with @attribute [Authorize] in _Imports.razor.  I can't seem to set different layouts / pages for NotFound route, based on Authorized property. How did you solve your case in that regard?