# Require Authenticated User (For entire app)

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, blazor, blazor-webassembly

How can I configure my Blazor WebAssembly to require authenticated users for the entire app rather than mark each page or controllers with the [Authorize] attribute?

My app should only allow authorized users, and the recommended configuration loads a little bit of the page before redirecting to the login.

Comment: What about to define: `public class AuthComponentBase: ComponentBase` with `[Authorize]`  and inherit your components from it?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is stand alone an easy way is simply add a new `_Imports.razor` in the pages folder.
Then put this line in it.

`@attribute [Authorize]`

If it is self hosted.
Try this [link](https://damienbod.com/2021/03/08/securing-blazor-web-assembly-using-cookies/) to add global Auth with no tokens in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I configure my Blazor WebAssembly to require authenticated users for the entire app rather than mark each page or controllers with the [Authorize] attribute?

You can check the authentication status on the main page's load and decide what to do next.

> My app should only allow authorized users, and the recommended configuration loads a little bit of the page before redirecting to the login.

Copy code bellow to the `Index.razor`

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
@code{ 

    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; }

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        var authState = await authenticationStateTask;
        var user = authState.User;

        if(!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Navigation.NavigateTo($"authentication/login?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(Navigation.Uri)}");
        }
    }
}
```

There is some [other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60687879/require-authorization-on-all-blazor-pages?answertab=active#tab-top) suggesting to add `@attribute [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Authorize]` on `_Imports.cs` and `@attribute [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AllowAnonymous]` on the pages which doesnt need authorization. This never worked for me as expected, but good to know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[Authorize]` in your layout page.

Answer (score 0):

> My app should only allow authorized users, and the recommended configuration loads a little bit of the page before redirecting to the login.

You should be doing this in the `App.razor` file. It will execute way before anything else and will ensure the user is authenticated and authorized before rendering any other component.

```html
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" PreferExactMatches="@true">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (context.User.Identity != null && !context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p>You are not authorized to access this resource.</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    <Loader />
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col text-center">
                        <h2>Looks like you're lost, we didn't find anything at this location.</h2>
                        <p>Try navigating to the Dashboard or going back in the browser.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```