# How to get login prompt with Blazor and Azure B2C

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, blazor, azure-ad-b2c

My non authorized pages give the "Not authorized" text instead of a login prompt.

[image]

I would instead like the login prompt as below.

[image]

I can only get this if I add authorization to the /_Host file but then my landing page (/Index), that has no layout, also requires a login.

How do I get the login prompt on all pages except my landing page?

I'm using .NET 6. Here's my Program.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;
using BlazorB2C.Data;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/_Host");
})
    .AddMvcOptions(options => { })
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");

app.Run();
```

Comment: could you please provide your `appsettings.json`

Comment: Here's my apsettings.json

`{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "********",
    "ClientId": "********-****-****-****-************",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Domain": "********",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SignUpSignIn",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_PasswordReset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_EditProfile"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}`

Comment: Here is a thread worth checking -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60687879/require-authorization-on-all-blazor-pages/60688109#60688109
If it doesn't help you might have to end up creating different Layout pages for authenticated and not-authenticated users.

Answer (score 0):

•   I would suggest you to please ensure that **‘LoginMode’** property of the **‘MsalProviderOptions’** also includes the redirect method as the ***framework defaults to pop-up login mode and falls back to redirect login mode if a pop-up can't be opened*** as below: -

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
 {
...
options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
});
```

Once the above is done, then kindly refer to the below documentation link regarding the **app component (App.razor)** which redirects the unauthorized users to the login page.

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory-b2c?view=aspnetcore-6.0#app-component**

Comment: I'm using Blazor Server. Is 'AddMsalAuthentication' available to both Blazor Server and WebAssembly?